# Densifying OpenStreetMap (OSM) network nodes?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, sql, pgrouting

I am working with osmconverter to convert osm files(*.osm) to *.pbf, then i use osm2po to get sql file that run into PostGis to get a network table.

The last step is to run a createTopology statement in SQL PostGis Editor to get the vertices of network.

However, this proccess only creates the initial and final nodes of a network stretch intersection and i would like to add more nodes between initial and final ones.

Editing the osm2po.config file of osm2po could be a posibility?

Comment: The core of graph theory is to compress everything to nodes and edges https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory. The usual way to show the real route is to connect the edges of the graph to real way geometries by common IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to add vertices with QGis and the tools like Densifyng geometries but it seems work well with selected segments.I will try the option to connect the egdes to real way geometries using IDs.

Comment: This is easy reading with images and shows an example about how it can be done https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=VirtualNetwork+reloaded.

Comment: I did not know the properties of the database manager SpatiaLite data. I will study the application on said case and the final results.
Thank you very much .